# Doctrine2 QueryBuilder subquery with SUM?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I'm trying to get Hotels from my database that have enough beds (user specifies guest count parameter). The query should look like this:

```
SELECT h.* FROM Hotel AS h
WHERE 
    (SELECT SUM(r.guestCount * r.count) 
    FROM Room AS r 
    WHERE r.hotel_id = h.id) >= $questCount
```

The above query contains subquery in the where clause. I've read doctrine's QueryBuilder documentation and I don't know how to make subquery in QB.

All I have now is:

```
$qb = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('h')
    ->from('AAAHotelsBundle:Hotel', 'h')
    ->where(.........???...........);
```

Any ideas what to do next?

Of course I simplified the problem (the query itself is much more complex). I use Symfony2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this DQL will help you

```
SELECT h, SUM(r.guestCount * r.count) as TSUM FROM Hotel h JOIN h.room r
WHERE TSUM  >= :questCount
```

Answer (score 2):

DQL is not a solution in my case. I do really need to use QueryBuilder.
I've [asked the same question on Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/doctrine-user/N5k_XZYd4II/7_npWsnei3AJ) and here is the solution:

```
$qb = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder() 
    ->select('h') 
    ->from('AAAHotelsBundle:Hotel', 'h') 
    ->join('Room', 'r') 
    ->groupBy('h') 
    ->having('SUM(r.guestCount * r.count) >= :guestCount') 
    ->setParameter("guestCount", $guestCount);
```